# java.io.FileNotFoundException: .. (No such file or directory) when retrieving DAOs

Tags: java, database, derby, dao

Project Due tomorrow so it would be great if someone could help me with this. I get the following errors when trying to access DAOs in my derby database. In my case I have a class called BandDAO and im trying to retrieve info stored in the db such as Band_Name etc

Errors:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: sql\createdb.txt (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: sql\insertdata.sql (No such file or directory)

I reckon the problem is somewhere in this class.  I read on one forum to change the \\ to / as I am using a mac. While it removed the above errors  it produced a number of different errors. Any ideas? and thanks

```
public class SetupDb {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class.getName());

void createTables() {

    DBManager dmbgr = new DBManager();

    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();

    executeSqlScript(con, new File("sql\\createdb.txt"));
}

void insertSetupData() {

    DBManager dmbgr = new DBManager();

    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();


    executeSqlScript(con, new File("sql\\insertdata.sql"));
}

public void showData() {

    Statement stmt;

    DBManager dmbgr = new DBManager();

    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from USERDATA");

        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            String userName = results.getString(2);
            String fName = results.getString(3);
            String lName = results.getString(4);
            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + userName + "\t\t" + fName + "\t\t" + lName);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

}

public void executeSqlScript(Connection conn, File inputFile) {

    // Delimiter
    String delimiter = ";";

    // Create scanner
    Scanner scanner;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter(delimiter);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e1);
        return;
    }

    // Loop through the SQL file statements 
    Statement currentStatement = null;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        // Get statement 
        String rawStatement = scanner.next();
        try {
            // Execute statement
            currentStatement = conn.createStatement();
            currentStatement.execute(rawStatement);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } finally {
            // Release resources
            if (currentStatement != null) {
                try {
                    currentStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);;
                }
            }
            currentStatement = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your issue is right there in the exception you printed. FileNotFoundException. This means your project is not finding the needed file namely sql\createddb.txt You may want to check the way you have the file being found. Where is the file actually stored?

Comment: My project is stored on my desktop and is named Gigs.Within that folder i have a sql folder containing my createdb.text file.  Also I'm using netbeans so in the file tab of my Gigs project you can see the folder sql and within that is my createdb.text file

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty easy to get your desktop which I think is where your issue is coming from. You are never actually pointing your code to your desktop from what I can see. I would advise against the answer above because lets say for instance you change your username or something you are now pointing to a wrong path again. I would recommend getting your home path via: System.getProperty("user.home") which from there you can point anywhere. This will also allow you to use your code on different OS versions. I tested this on linux but the principal is the same for windows.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "Gigs"
            + File.separator + "Sql" + File.separator + "createdb.txt";
    System.out.println(filePath);

    //now I can open that file based on the path. 
    File file = new File(filePath);

    if (file.exists()) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("This is text from file: " + line);
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("No File Found");
    }
}
```

My output then appears as:

[image]